# send local files to specific remote hosts

Tags: ansible

I would like to copy the local files to remote hosts, the files in local are in the folder named by the remote host(as it shows in the screenshot), how could I send them to the remote host respectively? (*.pem in centos8-8 will be sent to centos8-8 only, etc). I tried group['clients'] as the loop but it does not work.
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the copy module with the magic variable `inventory_hostname`

```
- name: Copy dir
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: path/{{ inventory_hostname }}
    dest: pathdest
```

Comment: Thanks @Frenchy, I have figured it out after reading the magic_variables, thanks.